# Dimension of an algebraic submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm taking a course on smooth manifolds and the following exercise was given to me:

> If $P\in\mathbb{R}[X_1, ..., X_{n+1}]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ such that $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial X_1}, ..., \frac{\partial P}{\partial X_{n+1}}\right)$ is never zero, prove that $Z(P):=\{[x_1:\dots:x_{n+1}]\in \mathbb{RP}^n\mid P(x_1,\dots, x_{n+1})=0\}$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

Here was my attempt: by interpreting $P$ as a smooth function $P:\mathbb{RP}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\text{rank}(dP)\equiv 1$ in the whole domain, so by the constant rank theorem, $Z(P)=P^{-1}(0)$ is a regular submanifold of codimension $1$ (if this is wrong, please let me know).

First of all, the fact that $d$ was not important was really surprising to me. Also, it seemed to me that the condition $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial X_1}, ..., \frac{\partial P}{\partial X_{n+1}}\right)\neq 0$ was pretty strong, and made me wonder if it was really necessary. For example, taking $n=2$ and $P(X, Y, Z)=X^2-XZ+YZ$, we have $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial X}, \frac{\partial P}{\partial Y},\frac{\partial P}{\partial Z}\right)(0,0,0)= 0$, but $Z(P)$ is still a regular submanifold of codimension $1$ (right?).

So my question is if there's a more general way to analyse whether or not $Z(P)$ is a regular submanifold, i.e., without imposing $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial X_1}, ..., \frac{\partial P}{\partial X_{n+1}}\right)\neq 0$? And what would be the relationship between $d$ and the codimension of $Z(P)$? Thanks!

Comment: Careful: $P$ is *not* giving a function on $\Bbb{RP}^n$. Only its zero-set is a well-defined locus in projective space. You really do need to work locally in your standard coordinate patches $U_i = \{[x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}]: x_i\ne 0\}$ to get an actual smooth real-valued function.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... well, now I really don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider, for example, the function
$$f_{n+1}(u_1,\dots,u_n) = P(u_1,\dots,u_n,1)$$
defined for $[u_1,\dots,u_n,1]\in U_{n+1} \cong \Bbb R^n$. Apply the regular value theorem (or constant rank theorem) to the functions $f_i$, $i=1,\dots,n+1$. Note that every $x\in Z(P)$ belongs to at least one $U_i$.

Comment: By the regular value theorem, $f_{i}^{-1}(0)$ is a regular submanifold of $U_i$ (and thus a regular submanifold of $M$). So we need to prove that $Z(P)=f_{1}^{-1}(0)\cup ...\cup f_{n+1}^{-1}(0)$ is a regular submanifold. But in general it's not true that the union of regular submanifolds is a regular submanifold (for example, the union of two concurrent lines in the plane). Does that really work?

Comment: Good question! Your example isn't working with open subsets of the creature :) I'm not taking unions of submanifolds. I'm working in open sets that cover all of $M$.

Comment: you're not thinking of each $f_{i}^{-1}(0)$ as a regular submanifold? But isn't that exactely what the regular value theorem gives us?

Comment: I'm showing that every point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ so that $M\cap U$ is a manifold. Now think about your concurrent lines.

Answer (score -2):

Dimension is another word for the number of degrees of freedom in a space. If you have $n$ dimensions and you impose one equation, you typically reduce the dimension by 1 (so we say the resulting space has codimension 1). For only the count of degrees of freedom, it does not matter whether the relation imposed was polynomial of degree $d$, analytic, holomorphic, or smooth. The rule of thumb is, impose 1 relation, cut the dimension by 1. Impose 2 relations, cut dimension by 2, etc (though according to the particulars there may be deviations from this rule). The degree of the polynomial determines the shape of the submanifold/variety, like its genus, but not its dimension.

As for regularity, the criterion you mention is valid for submanifolds which are the vanishing locus of a single function. The general criterion is to look at the dimension of the tangent space. For a variety, this is a simple generalization, where you look at the differentials of all the functions your variety is the vanishing locus of.